# drupal views arguments - local vs global

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am working on the drupal frontend. I want to be able to set an argument for a drupal 6 view which will show up in one display but not in an other aka- make it local not global. Is this possible? Every time I try it keeps adding the argument to all of the displays of the view.

Answer (score 1):

yes this is possible: you need 2 displays (type page) with different URI`s

watch this
[youtube video: basic drupal views introduction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eV__oOckAPM)
If it wont help, please provide screen shoots of your current view configuration